# Paypal Classic API: Test accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I need to simulate a buyer transaction in my paypal sandbox environment. Essentially, a buyer is a user that decides to subscribe to my service, which is done using the Paypal NVP API method: DoDirectPayment.

Reading the documentation, I gather that a buyer in this case will essentially be a Personal account, and basically to make any kind of api call, I require API credentials. However, the PAYPAL Developer website does not show any kind of API credentials for this personal account :

[image]

I do have a business account, and that does state the corresponding API credentials. The link I am referring to is :
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox#credentials

where it states that the API credentials are specified for all accounts.

The only rationale I have behind this are :

a) personal accounts do not get API credentials,

b) I need to simulate a DoDirectPayment API with my business account API credentials, but documentation states that to simulate a buyer transaction I must use a personal account.

c) I need to set API credentials manually somehow.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use your API credentials from your business account in the API call.  As for the buyer, you would not be paying with a PayPal account if you are using the DoDirectPayment API.  You would be using a credit card.  You should be able to use any of the card numbers below to test with.  I juse use a Mod 10 check to generate the card numbers.  You can just use any valid future date for the exp date, and use 123 for the card security code.

Visa
4539261585419872
4532063588063153
4024007125711126
4916126222581496
4916335290325039
4929693226575720
4916573003035640
4485204470227566
4024007102338976
4024007148183980

Comment: thanks, good to see the Paypal dev team active and helpful. Are you guys experiencing any technical difficulties at the moment ? My sandbox behavior is erratic @ the moment

Comment: Unfortunately there have been some issues reported with the launch of the new sandbox site.  We are actively working to resolve these issues as quickly as possible.  Some of the issues can be cleared up by using Firefox or Chrome instead of IE, and clearing your cookies and cache prior to opening up the browser and navigating to the new sandbox site.

Comment: yep, cleared cookies and cache, and only use Firefox/Chrome. nO IE (I am a web dev :p) . Will do this again, and give you a heads up if anything changed right here, thanks for your hel p

Comment: any expected idea when the API's are expected to be back up again? still unable to visit api.paypal.com ...thanks much

Comment: Whats the error that you are getting back when trying to make an API call?